# Request from Arduino to API Docker

Tags: docker, api, docker-compose, nestjs, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino project. I want to make a request from Arduino (outside the container) to an API in a Docker container.

Everything is on localhost. I try to connect from Arduino with WifiClient to 127.0.0.1:3001 (host and port of my API in Docker). But the client does not connect.

My code:

WifiCliente client;

```
char url5[] = "127.0.0.1";
const int   port = 3001;   

if (!client.connect(url5, port)) {
  Serial.println("Fallo al conectar");
 return;
}
```

¡Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does your docker iamge expose the port `3001` and does it map to whatever port the docker image is hosting internally?

Comment: This is mi port result in docker ps command 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp. I test in swagger with 127.0.0.1:3001 and it works, but Arduino doesn't connect. I also tried with 0.0.0.0 as a host, but it didn't work.

Comment: And the arduino runs on the same host as the docker container?

Comment: No. Arduino runs outside the container.

Comment: So they aren't on the same machine at all, correct?

Comment: No. Both are in the same computer locally. Meanwhile docker api container runs, arduino outside from this container makes the request.

Comment: Arduino is a separate device. localhost on Arduino is Arduino. use a real IP address of the server

Comment: How can I get my real IP address from docker local container? I mean, how can I connect Arduino to my local network (MyPC) to connect to my localhost?

Comment: your previous comment are two question different than the original question. the first is not suitable for SO, the second is more suitable for Arduino SE